Confusion about virtual subclasses in static type checking like mypy
I'm trying to figure out in python whether virtual subclass will pass the static type check like mypy. And I read about this in fluent python:

Virtual subclasses do not inherit from their registered ABCs, and
are not checked for conformance to the ABC interface at any time,
not even when they are instantiated. Also, static type checkers can’t
handle virtual subclasses at this time. For details, see Mypy issue
2922—ABCMeta.register support.

It seems that mypy doesn't support virtual class created using register or __subclasshool__.  I wrote the following code to test this and encountered a confusing result:
from collections import abc


class SequenceLike:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self._list = list(lst)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._list[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._list)

    def __contains__(self, object):
        return object in self._list

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._list)


def checkSized(a: abc.Sized):
    pass


def checkSequence(a: abc.Sequence[int]):
    pass


def checkContainer(a: abc.Container):
    pass


def checkIterable(a: abc.Iterable):
    pass


abc.Sequence.register(SequenceLike)

checkSized(SequenceLike([]))
checkContainer(SequenceLike([1, 2]))
checkIterable(SequenceLike([]))
checkSequence(SequenceLike([1, 2, 3])) # mypy error: Argument 1 to "checkSequence" has incompatible type "SequenceLike"; expected "Sequence[int]"  [arg-type]

So, my question is, why do the calls to checkSized(SequenceLike([])), checkContainer(SequenceLike([1, 2])), and checkIterable(SequenceLike([])) not trigger any mypy errors, given that the SequenceLike class is effectively a virtual subclass of Sized, Container, and Iterable?
I appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you!
Ps. English is my second language, so please excuse any errors in my question.

You're just lucky: all of Sized, Container and Iterable are Protocols (see Strutural subtyping PEP). Basically this means that anything with __len__(self)->str defined conforms to the Sized protocol - explicit inheritance plays no role here, and neither registering does.

The checks pass since SequenceLike conforms to the Sized, Container, Iterable Protocols defined in typeshed which Mypy checks against. The Sequence check does not pass since it is not defined as a Protocol in typeshed
Mypy does not call __subclasshook__ or issubclass/isinstance.
See this answer for more:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71819704/9241227
